# pre_get_posts not limiting posts per pages

Tags: wordpress, search

I have set up the following in my functions.php to raise the limit of posts being shown when doing a public search:

```
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 20);

    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_results_query' );
```

But however much I tried to modify it, I don't seem to have any effect. What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried disable plugins ?

Comment: Could you please include the full function `search_results_query`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing part of your code but do you have $query set to pass through your function?

```php
function search_results_query( $query ) {
```

I just tested your code and set it to 1 using the 2019 theme and it worked fine with the above.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the problem was that the theme had already set the posts per pages. I managed to change the number of posts from the appearance menu. The page template had already theme actions and hooks and I have a limited understanding yet of it all, but I think that was what was interfering with my hook. Or I just simply didn't understand fully how to hook it up properly. Either way, I resolved it.